# IUserType & UserTypeConvention<> Equivalent In Entity Framework (Code First)

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate, code-first

Is there an [NHibernate] `IUserType` and [Fluent-NHibernate] `UserTypeConvention<>` equivalent in Entity Framework? Code First perhaps?

Comment: You wish! Did you know EF *still* does not support Enum properties?? EF is as extensible as a spoon.

Comment: Reason for the rant: I'm being forced to use EF in a new project, and it's a huge downgrade coming from NHibernate.

Comment: Ouch this is a huge show stopper IMO.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still the case?

Comment: Yes, this is still the case as of EF 5.0.0  We are switching to NHibernate in part because of this.